# mysql jdbc unsuccessful rollback

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, rollback, autocommit

I've got some Java code uses JDBC to connect to a MySQL database, then the code does some read operations then a single update, all using the same connection. If there is an exception, then `connection.rollback()` is called; if there's no exception, `connection.commit()` is called. At this stage, the connection is newly created each time I run my test (i.e. it does not come from a pool). My code only ever creates one connection, and it is used throughout the test.

The connection being used has `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` called immediately after the connection instance is created.

For some reason, when there is an exception and `connection.rollback()` is called, it turns out that my update has been committed rather than rolled back.

Via debugging, I have confirmed the following,

- After calling `connection.setAutoCommit(false)`, `connection.getAutoCommit()` returns a value of `false`, as expected. Also, `"Select @@session.autocommit"` returns a value of `0`, indicating that auto commit is off, as expected.
- Immediately prior to calling `connection.rollback()`, the same checks show that auto commit is off, as expected.
- `connection.commit()` is definitely not being called and `connection.rollback()` is definitely being called.

I have also tried explicitly running the statement `"rollback;"` but it does not solve my issue. I have also tried explicitly running the statement `"Set AUTOCOMMIT = 0;"` after creating the connection.

All of my tables use a storage engine of InnoDB. Via SQL Workbench, with auto commit off, rollbacks and commits work as expected.

I am using MySQL version '5.0.91-community-nt'. The MySQL jdbc driver version is 5.1.19. I'm using Java 5.

Has anyone got any suggestions as to why my update is getting committed even though auto-commit is off, commit is never called, and rollback is explicitly called?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The code I refer to in the OP is not in a single block, it is dispersed across classes. To satisfy the queries above for examples of the code, I prepared a single block of code to illistrate the issue. Once the block of code was completed, I tested it to ensure I could replicate the issue. Well, I couldn't replicate the issue - the rollback worked just fine. This caused me to go through the production code to work out all the things it was doing beyond the block of code I had put together.

It turns out that the production code both creates and drops temporary tables. Most relevant, it drops the temporary tables after performing the update, and it drops the temporary tables whether or not there is an exception. It turns out that dropping a table in MySQL issues an implicit commit call. Hence, in between my code throwing an exception and my code calling connection.rollback(), it drops tables which causes an implicit call to commit. Hence my 'auto commit' issue.

Comment: check this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730621/do-ddl-statements-always-give-you-an-implicit-commit-or-can-you-get-an-implicit). All DDL commands perform a commit.

Comment: Yes, but not all DDL causes a commit. For instance, the creation of temporary tables I refer to above does not cause an implicit commit. I'm not sure if different vendors do it differently to one another but I have now found the definitive list of DDL operations that cause an implicit commit in MySQL. Cheers.

Comment: @richardtz That question refers to Oracle. Actual commit behavior of DDL is database dependent (one of the reasons that you have [`DatabaseMetaData.dataDefinitionCausesTransactionCommit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#dataDefinitionCausesTransactionCommit()).