# What is the appropriate way to do something like defining a user function in SQL during testing?

Tags: java, sql, transactions, derby

For a particular integration test that is backed by a Derby database I need to introduce a user function before I execute my test.

The steps look like this:

- *start transaction*
- *create function*
- *commit transaction* >>problem here<<
- *execute DB operations and test*

The problem is that I need to commit after creating the user function in order to use it later in a query. *Is this the case for all operations that affect system tables?* Now I can't roll back all my DB operations because there has already been a commit. How do I roll back the whole toot?

Comment: Why do you have to roll everything back?

Comment: @BryanPendleton Between different cucumber scenarios I want a clean database.

Comment: Four ways to do that: (1) have a re-usable script that drops and recreates all your tables, indexes, views, etc. I always have one of these. (2) Use an In-memory database (3) create a new separate database for each run. (4) Using JDBC metadata, write a bit of code that iterates through all the schema objects and drops them.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, any DDL statement execution itself means COMMIT of a transaction in progress. So, I think the place where you execute the sql script of create function, you are committing the transaction there itself.

Refer this:

[Do DDL statements always give you an implicit commit, or can you get an implicit rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730621/do-ddl-statements-always-give-you-an-implicit-commit-or-can-you-get-an-implicit)