# After truncate with `.createSQLQuery` spring/hibernate does not rollback transaction

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, junit, transactions

I cannot understand why Spring `@Transactional` test method Hibernate does not rollback changes that were made in `@Before`? There is [information](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-tx-before-and-after-tx) that `@Before` and `@Test` are called within one transaction. All contexts may consider to be configured.

```
@Test
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional(defaultRollback = true, transactionManager = "transactionManager")
public class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private EntityDao entityDao;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        // create arbitrary entity
        Entity one = Utils.createEntity();
        // save with HibernateDao to table_1
        entityDao.save(one);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("TRUNCATE table_2").executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Without `createSQLQuery().executeUpdate` all changes in `@Before` are rollbacked as required.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Not all of them support transactional TRUNCATE

Comment: I'm using mysql and it is said that [`Truncate operations cause an implicit commit, and so cannot be rolled back`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html). Could you explain by means of gestures why it is the problem that some dbms doesn't support transactional truncate? I'd wanna know how it happens in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` query in Mysql implicitly commits the transaction (as it is considered to be a DDL query: it drops and recreates a table). DDL queries generally cause commits.

If you need a transactionally-well-behaving alternative, you could use `DELETE FROM <table-name>`.

**Update**

More information: [Do DDL statements always give you an implicit commit, or can you get an implicit rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730621/do-ddl-statements-always-give-you-an-implicit-commit-or-can-you-get-an-implicit)